# i am getting error during compilation of a flutter project with the flutter_typeahead package version 4.3.1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Compile failed

../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:898:40: Error: Member not found: 'Scrollable.maybeOf'.

```
final scrollableState = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
```

This is the build error

Below is the code where flutter_typeahead is used.

`class LocationSearchDialog extends StatelessWidget {
final GoogleMapController mapController;
LocationSearchDialog({@required this.mapController});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: ResponsiveHelper.isWeb() ? 80 : 0),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: Material(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.RADIUS_SMALL)),
    child: SizedBox(
        width: Dimensions.WEB_MAX_WIDTH,
        child: TypeAheadField(
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
            controller: _controller,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
            autofocus: true,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'search_location'.tr,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.none, width: 0),
              ),
              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.copyWith(
                    fontSize: Dimensions.fontSizeDefault,
                    color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
                  ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
            ),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.color,
                  fontSize: Dimensions.fontSizeLarge,
                ),
          ),
          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
            return await Get.find<LocationController>()
                .searchLocation(context, pattern);
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, PredictionModel suggestion) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
              child: Row(children: [
                Icon(Icons.location_on),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(suggestion.description,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.copyWith(
                            color:
                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.color,
                            fontSize: Dimensions.fontSizeLarge,
                          )),
                ),
              ]),
            );
          },
          onSuggestionSelected: (PredictionModel suggestion) async {
            Position _position = await Get.find<LocationController>()
                .setLocation(suggestion.placeId, suggestion.description,
                    mapController);
            Get.back(result: _position);
          },
        )),
  ),
);
```

}
}`

Help me to fix it guys;(

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update `flutter_typeahead: ^4.6.2` which is the latest version. And try to upgrade your `Flutter` sdk.

It will be resolved.